# How to describe conjugacy classes for elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$?

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

I am totally new to mathematical analysis and just learn what group is. In a problem it says to describe conjugacy class for $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. But what is the conjugate class this group?

Comment: That group is abelian, conjugation is trivial on abelian groups.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a group $G$, the conjugacy class of an element $h\in G$ is all the elements of the form $g\cdot h\cdot g^{-1}$ for $g\in G$. In your case, the conjugacy class of $(0,1)$ consists of the elements:

$$
\begin{split} (0,0)+(0,1)+(0,0)&=(0,1) \\ (0,1)+(0,1)+(0,1)&=(0,1) \\ (1,0)+(0,1)+(1,0)&=(0,1) \\ (1,1)+(0,1)+(1,1)&=(0,1) \end{split}
$$

Note that there is only one element in the conjugacy class of $(0,1)$ which is $(0,1)$. This is because the group is abelian so in all cases $g\cdot h\cdot g^{-1}=g\cdot g^{-1}\cdot h=h$, which is what Adam Hughes meant by the conjugation being trivial. The conjugacy classes of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ are therefore the sets consisting of each element individually:

$$
\begin{split} Cl((0,0))&=\{(0,0)\} \\ Cl((0,1))&=\{(0,1)\} \\ Cl((1,0))&=\{(1,0)\} \\ Cl((1,1))&=\{(1,1)\}\end{split}
$$

So $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has four conjugacy classes each consisting of one element.

Comment: Sorry I still have difficulty understanding what $g^{-1}$ means...Also, does $ghg^{-1}$ stand for using the operation in the group on $(gh)g^{-1}$??

Comment: And actually my problem is what the conjugacy class of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is instead of $(0,1)$. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ does not have a conjugacy class. A group doesn't have a conjugacy class, you need to talk about conjugacy classes of elements. $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is probably a bad example because nothing interesting happens and each element is it's own inverse. $g^{-1}$ means the inverse of $g$ in the group. That is, $g^{-1}$ is the element that you 'multiply' $g$ by to get the identity. In $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, the inverse of $(0,1)$ is $(0,1)$ since $(0,1)+(0,1)=(0,0)$ and $(0,0)$ is the identity.

Comment: And yes, I was using $ghg^{-1}$ to mean $g\cdot h\cdot g^{-1}$ where $\cdot$ is the group operation. In the case of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ the group operation is just addition.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It really clarifies things a lot.